# Rails, OpenID and Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authlogic, authlogic-oid, railscasts

I've been following [ryan baytes screencast #170](http://railscasts.com/episodes/170-openid-with-authlogic) and adding [ruby-openid](http://github.com/pelle/ruby-openid), [authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) and [authlogic-oid](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_openid) to an existing authlogic authentication system.

However, I keep getting the following stack of errors:

NameError (uninitialized constant OpenIdAuthentication::InvalidOpenId):
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/authlogic-oid-1.0.4/lib/authlogic_openid/session.rb:53:in `openid_identifier='
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/authlogic-oid-1.0.4/lib/authlogic_openid/session.rb:47:in`credentials='
    authlogic (2.1.2) lib/authlogic/session/foundation.rb:28:in `initialize'
    authlogic (2.1.2) lib/authlogic/session/password.rb:140:in`initialize'
    authlogic (2.1.2) lib/authlogic/session/activation.rb:48:in `initialize'
    authlogic (2.1.2) lib/authlogic/session/klass.rb:61:in`initialize'
    authlogic (2.1.2) lib/authlogic/session/scopes.rb:79:in `initialize'
    app/controllers/user_sessions_controller.rb:10:in`new'
    app/controllers/user_sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'

Is there anyone who's facing the same kind of problem? I'm using rails 2.3.4

I've tried [binary's example app](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_openid) which is working perfectly well (rails 2.1.2), I've tried [the code provided by Ryan Bates](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/170-openid-with-authlogic) and it is working well too (rails 2.3.2). So, the libraries are working with previous versions of rails.

Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rails/open_id_authentication plugin has been updated a few days ago and it breaks compatibility with the authlogic_openid gem (v=1.0.4).

Youl'll have to wait until someone fix the authlogic_openid gem (the issue)

Answer (score 0):

I have found this:

http://futureadapter.com/2009/11/13/authlogic-plugin-errorfix/

But I don't know how to apply this code ( were to I put it ? ) so that it fixes the authlogic_oid problem.

Can anyone check it out and see how to apply it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://testingauth.heroku.com/

Authlogic setup with openid and jquery selector.

Source:
http://github.com/shripadk/authlogic_openid_selector_example

Answer (score -1):

Briefly... no

i guess there are too many dependent libraries and debugging the problem took a bit of time, so we shifted to using masquerade, making the app itself an openid provider.